# Newton's method and fixed point

Tags: numerical-methods

> Can anyone explain this problem? I am wondering what it means for evaluate $g'(x^∗)$, isn't that zero?

Newton's method can be viewed as a way of transforming a root-finding problem $f(x)=0$ into a fixed-point problem $x=g(x)$, where $$g(x)=x−f(x)/f′(x).$$ Recall that for simple roots, Newton's method has a quadratic convergence rate since $g'(x^∗)=0$, where $$g′(x)=f(x)f''(x)/(f'(x))^2.$$

When there is a root with multiplicity, $f'(x^∗)= 0$ which leads to a division by $0$ in $g'(x^∗)$.
We will study how this affects the convergence rate of Newton's Method.

Consider the function $$f(x)=(x−x^∗)^m * h(x),$$ where $m$ is an integer greater than $1$ and $h$ is arbitrary function such that $h(x^∗)≠0$

> Please answer the following:
>
> - What is the fixed point problem obtained by applying Newton's Method? Please give the formula for $g(x)$.
> - Evaluate $g'(x^∗)$. Based on that value, what can you conclude about the convergence rate of Newton's Method for a root of multiplicity $m$?
> - Based on the previous result, can you propose a modified Newton's method that recovers quadratic convergence rate? What is the formula for $g(x)$
>   in this modified version? Prove that your new method achieves quadratic convergence.

Comment: Your question is somewhat hard to follow, as the mathematics is poorly formatted.  You are much more likely to get constructive feedback if you use MathJax to correctly format your question.

Comment: Also you could provide the reference (where does this text come from)

Comment: I think you were already told what $g(x)$ is earlier in the problem As for the modified Newton's method two of the Related links https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93156/newtons-method-for-roots-of-multiplicity-1?rq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662906/newtons-modified-method?rq=1 already address this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rate of convergence of Newton's method near a double root.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2614354/rate-of-convergence-of-newtons-method-near-a-double-root) or older [Newton's Function Confusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676888/newtons-function-confusion).

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt[m]{f(x)}$ has a simple root.